# Power BI Gantt Chart. Multiple end dates for a start date

Tags: powerbi, dax, gantt-chart

I have multiple end dates for a start date, such as the planned end date and the real end date.
I want them both on one line and in different colors to show how much time has been added to a project.
I am using Microsoft's Gantt 2.2.3.
Is there a way to implement this like shown in the picture?
[image: Example]

I tried to look it up on YouTube and on the Microsoft site, but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Microsoft Gantt doesn't have this feature. You might want to try: [Definitive Logic Advanced Gantt Chart](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-gb/product/power-bi-visuals/definitivelogic.dl-advanced-gantt?tab=Overview) - or - [GANTT by Lingaro](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-gb/product/power-bi-visuals/lingaro.ganttbylingaro?tab=Overview)